# Support for @Streaming in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

Because there is no `body().in()` (anymore), this code does not work in retrofit 2:

```
interface Service {        
    @Get("...") 
    @Streaming
    Response getData();
}

try (InputStream in = service.getData().getBody().in()) {
    ...
}
```

Only way I found is this. Is this correct?

```
try (InputStream in = service.getData().raw().body().byteStream()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but I had the same issue today so here's what I found and use :

```
interface Service {
    @GET("...")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}


Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getData();
try {
    InputStream in = call.execute().body().byteStream();
    (...)
} catch (IOException e) {...}
```