# Android Retrofit2: read from async delayed http page

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

i'm using latest retrofit2 android library version and i have a problem getting a page which contain a single table that loads his data asynchronously.

i call the page -> page responds with 200 -> page start gathering data and shows it progressively.

if i call the retrofit2 interface, it grab sometimes 60 elements, other times 100 elements.

if i load that page with any browser, it takes 2 seconds and shows 600 elements.

how can i delay retrofit2 (or okHttp) after he receive the 200 response?

Thank you

Comment: Implement pagination for the api response and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [@Streaming](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Streaming.html) annotation which allows you to get the data as a stream. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454436/5137879).